# Terraform plan leads to: '"archive": openpgp: signature made by unknown entity' error

Tags: terraform

It was working before, but today I have:

> Error installing provider "archive": openpgp: signature made by unknown entity.

I tried to install this plugin plugin manually, but having the same problem

Comment: I think you've encountered the problem described in [Terraform Updates for HCSEC-2021-12](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/terraform-updates-for-hcsec-2021-12/23570).

Answer (score 1):

This can happen on Terraform v0.11. To fix, specify a version:

```
provider "archive" {
  version = "1.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We had this issue on Terraform version 0.11.4.
Bumping to 0.11.5 and specifying archive provider version 1.3.0 fixed the issue.

Version 11.4 specifies the following was added, which might have fixed the issue:

> cli: Update the HashiCorp Public Key (#28498)

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/releases/tag/v0.11.15